# Как узнать, какой файл исправил chkdsk?

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система, ntfs, диск

Как узнать, что за файл скрывается под номером 3856B и что за индекс $I30?

```
Этап 2. Проверка связей имен файлов...
Исправление ошибки в индексе $I30 файла 3856B.
  Обработано записей индекса: 1194200.
Проверка индексов завершена.
  Проверено неиндексированных файлов: 0.
  Восстановлено неиндексированных файлов в утерянное и найденное: 0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял

*3856B* - номер записи в MFT (соответствует полю *FILE record number* структуры [File Reference](http://ftp.kolibrios.org/users/Asper/docs/NTFS/ntfsdoc.html#concept_file_reference))

*$I30* - указывает на индекс файлов в каталоге ([один из типов индексов](http://ftp.kolibrios.org/users/Asper/docs/NTFS/ntfsdoc.html#id4758101))

т.е. сообщение значит, что поврежден список файлов в каталоге с указанным номером

---

Для того, чтобы узнать имя файла по его номеру записи в MFT, в Windows существует команда **fsutil file queryfilenamebyid**. Проблема в том, что эта команда требует полный ID файла вида *0x7500000000CFCD* (состоящий из номера записи и дополнительного однобайтового значения SequenceNumber, которое показывает, сколько раз данная запись была повторно использована), в то время как журнал программы проверки диска возвращает только частичный идентификатор вида *0x00000000CFCD* (только номер записи). Теоретически, для идентификации файла достаточно только номера записи, т.к. он представляет собой индекс массива. Дополнительный байт, как я понял, нужен для контроля правильности действий при обращении к повторно используемым записям, поэтому все "высокоуровневные" средства Windows, например WMI, используют полный идентификатор.

Тем не менее, есть способ найти файл и по частичному идентификатору. Для этого понадобится утилита nfi.exe из пакета [Windows 2000 OEM Support Tools](http://web.archive.org/web/20041206105853/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253066/en-us). К сожалению, сей антиквариат более не доступен с официального сайта, однако на свой страх и риск его можно скачать здесь: [Oem3sr2s.zip](https://yadi.sk/d/bLe0dRwl3TdVCB). Данная консольная утилита позволяет сделать дамп MFT указанного тома. 
Использование:

```
nfi.exe (БукваДиска):>filename.txt
```

Затем в полученном файле надо искать переведенное в десятичную систему значение номера записи из chkdsk. В результате будет найдено что-то такое (для каталога):

```
File 53197

\foo\bar\catalog\

    $STANDARD_INFORMATION (resident)

    $FILE_NAME (resident)

    $FILE_NAME (resident)

    $INDEX_ROOT $I30 (resident)
```

---

**Примечания**

1. Можно найти файл подбором, вызывайте в цикле команду, пока не получите `%ERRORLEVEL%` равный 0:

   ```
   fsutil file queryfilenamebyid (БукваДиска):\ 0xXX00000012CFCA
   ```

   где XX изменяется в диапазоне от 00 до FF

   При наличии node.js это можно сделать следующим образом:

   ```
   const spawn = require("child_process").spawnSync;

   for (var q=0; q<256; ++q) {
     var id = "0x" + (0+q.toString(16)).slice(-2) + "00000003856B";
     var args = ["file", "queryfilenamebyid", "h:\\", id];

     if(!spawn("fsutil", args).status) {
       console.log(id);
       /* 866-я кодировка не считывается нормально, поэтому перезапускаем */
       spawn("fsutil", args, {stdio:'inherit'});
     }
   }
   ```
2. Аналогом `nfi.exe` в Linux является утилита [`ntfsls`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsls), запущенная с ключом -i

Comment: Эм.. а как найти соответствующий каталог?

Comment: попробуйте fsutil file queryfilenamebyid (БукваДиска): (ДесятичныйНомер)

Comment: как оказалось, не все так просто... внес изменения в ответ

Comment: Что-то не очень хочется пытаться запустить системную утилиту из Win2000 на 64-битной десятке. А уж из левого источника - тем более. Кстати, а если в линукс залезть (есть Минт) - может там какие утилиты подходящие имеются? И ещё, а можно ведь SequenceNumber просто перебрать, пока не получится верный идентификатор?

Comment: Да, можно и подбирать. для файлов, которые часто перезаписывались, это займет некоторое время (но, по сравнению с полным дампом MFT на больших томах, может даже быстрее выйдет). В Linux, попробуйте [ntfsls](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsls) с ключом -i, должна работать аналогично nfi.

Comment: Круто! Всё получилось! Добавил код для перебора на nodejs - что-то так и не разобрался, как это обычным bat'ником сделать.